# How to call a javascript function once on page load, page reloads, don't call it again

Tags: javascript, forms, magento, refresh

On a Magento shopping cart, there are 2 forms that need to be filled out: shipping estimate and coupon code. Each refreshes the page after submitting the form. The shipping estimate form needs to be submitted before the coupon form so that the coupon can validate the country.

What I'd like to do is to call the shipping form's `coShippingMethodForm.submit()` on load. That way the country is loaded, and then the coupon form will check the country. This has the added advantage that the initial shipping rates are displayed without requiring the user to submit the form.

My challenge: if I call `coShippingMethodForm.submit()` on load - it will refresh the page and then continuously refresh b/c the `coShippingMethodForm.submit()` keeps submitting and refreshing.

How do I call that function once, page refreshes, and not run again (unless the user clicks the submit button).

[Example Magento cart page I'm referring to](http://shop.merchantguru.com/index.php/checkout/cart/)

Comment: Sounds like a job for... AJAX!

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a lot of refreshing... maybe some JavaScript wouldn't hurt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookie to prevent resumbit on reload.
Function js for broswer cookie can be found here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
In your JS function coShippingMethodForm.submit

```
coShippingMethodForm.submit = function(){
     //check cookie here
     if(readCookie('already_submit')==1)
          return;
     createCookie('already_submit', 1, 1); //for 1 day
     //old code here
}
```

And on submit button, add eraseCookie line:

```
<input type="submit" id="your_submit_button" 
       onclick="eraseCookie('already_submit');" />
```

Comment: Both answers here probably would work, but they made me realize a better way: check to see if the shipping rates div is present or not. If not, then submit coShippingMethodForm. Here's the JS is used:

  window.loaded=shippingLoaded();
   function shippingLoaded() {
    if (checkobject("co-shipping-method-form")) {
     coShippingMethodForm.submit();
    }
   }
   function checkobject(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById(obj)) { return false; } else { return true; }
   }

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using PHP, why not just have a hidden form
`<input type='hidden' name='countrySubmitted' value='true' />`
and then when php renders the page check to see if the value is set, if not then call the function to submit.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
if (isset($_POST['countrySubmitted']))
echo "document.coShippingMethodForm.Submit();";
echo "</script>";
```