# How to code a javascript countdown timer in a JSP page so reloading doesn't restart the timer?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a javascript function once on page load, page reloads, don't call it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455532/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-once-on-page-load-page-reloads-dont-call-it)

I want call a javascript in a jsp page, that triggers a countdown timer. However, if the user refreshes the page, I don't want the timer to be reset - it should continue from the time remaining. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455532/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-once-on-page-load-page-reloads-dont-call-it

Comment: Absolutely the sam way as in simple html page.

Answer (score 2):

In your comments, you say you want a timer that doesn't restart every time the page is loaded. This is what I would do...

Assume that your page is called `timer.jsp` and in there you have a script that starts counting down a timer. I would therefore do the following...

1. When you're generating the `timer.jsp` page for the first time, create a `session` parameter called `TimerFinish` that contains the date-time that the timer should *finish*. For example, if the date-time is `01/01/2012 10:00` and your timer is for `25` minutes, you would store the value `01/01/2012 10:25`.
2. Whenever the user displays the page (including the first page load and every page refresh), this `TimerFinish` value will already exist. You can use this to calculate how long the timer has until it should finish. Calculate this value as `TimerFinish - currentDateTime`
3. Set the timer in your javascript to start counting down from the value you calculated in step 2.

So, no matter what the user does (refreshing the page, etc), the timer will always start from the time remaining, and not simply reset to 25 minutes again. When `timer.jsp` is reloaded by the user, you just read the existing `TimerFinish` value from the `session` object and use that to set the correct value of the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is just a dynamic way to create HTML. So, your question is "how to call javascript on page loading?"

And the answer is.

Every script is executed when browser parses the page. Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>alert("from head");<script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>alert("from body");<script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also run script when page loading is finished. 
A lot of elements have `onload` event. For example `body` element. So, you can say:

`<body onload="alert('body is loaded')">`

So, the alert will be shown when body loading is finished.

Comment: sorry, actuaal my problem is that, i have timer in jsp page which start when we come on this page onload event, but we refresh page this onload again call and time again set. so plz give solution how can i call timer at one time and if any body refresh this page it will go on first page.

Comment: @user1116095 If the page is reloaded, the page is reloaded--why would you *not* want the timer to start over?

Comment: @DaveNewton, because, this jsp page has some question for quiz where time is limit.so i do not want start timer.